# Handle Pagination with only "Limit" and without "Skip" from the frontend

Tags: javascript, pagination, frontend, backend

I'm consuming a third-party API that doesn't have a `"skip"` parameter to skip a specific amount of rows, it only provides a `"limit"` param to only limit the fetched count, the thing is to handle pagination with this approach I will re-fetch some rows again with every request...

**Example** :in first page I'm fetching the first 10 rows, and in the second page I will update the limit param to fetch the first 20 rows **including the already fetched first 10 rows**, and so on with every page request.

so my solution was to make a **prefetch** of 100 rows and display them on the first 10 pages
*- as I'm displaying 10 rows per page -* and make a new request only on each multiples of 10 as the page numbers **1, 10, 20, 30, 40, and so on**...

so is this a qualified solution?, is there any other solution at all?

Comment: This would probably be a better question for the 3rd-party API provider. Maybe they use `offset` instead of `skip`? Your solution would still suffer having to re-fetch the already fetched 100 rows once you hit page 10 (assuming that actually happens; sorting/filtering, or upping "records per page" can be efficient in only ever returning a couple pages, i.e. when was the last time you actually navigated to page 10?)

Comment: Thanks, I've already asked them about ```offset``` or ```limit``` and they don't, that's why I'm thinking about the best workaround...
I know we still have the same performance issue with my solution, but is there any other solution?

Comment: Seems pretty crazy that isn't an option at all  I can't think of anything off the top of my head, and your approach _should_ work for most cases I would expect, but ultimately it sounds like a deficiency on their end...